# Stored procedure in Oracle is giving error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have written `stored procedure` but I am getting error as

> Error(6375,30): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null

Here is the procedure

```html
PROCEDURE INS_UPD_WF_BY_CMM_FTTX
(
  PJOB_PROGRESS_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.JOB_PROGRESS_ID%TYPE,  
  PHOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE IN NVARCHAR2,
  PLIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE IN NVARCHAR2,
  PAPPROVED_BY IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.APPROVED_BY%TYPE,  
  PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.APPROV_REJECT_REMARK%TYPE,
  PMODIFIED_BY IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.MODIFIED_BY%TYPE,
  PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID%TYPE,
  PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME%TYPE,
  PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID%TYPE,
  PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME%TYPE,
  PSTATUS_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.STATUS_ID%TYPE,
  PHOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH%TYPE,
  PLIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH%TYPE,
  POUTMSG OUT NVARCHAR2
)
AS
VCNT NUMBER:=0;
VCMMROUTE NUMBER:=0;
VCMMLIT NUMBER:=0;
VLENGTH_CHNG_CNT NUMBER:=0;
VJOB_ID NUMBER;
VSPAN_TYPE NVARCHAR2(20):='';
VSPAN_ID NVARCHAR2(50):='';
VLINK_ID NVARCHAR2(50):='';
VMAINTZONECODE VARCHAR2(50):='';
VNELEG NUMBER;
VNELEG1 NUMBER;                               
VNELEG2 NUMBER;                               
JOB_NE_LENGTH NUMBER;
BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO VLENGTH_CHNG_CNT
          FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
          WHERE JOB_PROGRESS_ID = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID
          AND HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH = PHOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH
          AND LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH = PLIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH;
        SELECT DISTINCT JOB_ID INTO VJOB_ID
          FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
          WHERE JOB_PROGRESS_ID = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;
          
BEGIN
        IF PSTATUS_ID = 4 OR THEN
        
BEGIN
        BEGIN
              UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
                SET HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE = TO_DATE(PHOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                    LIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE = TO_DATE(PLIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                    APPROVED_BY = PAPPROVED_BY,
                    APPROVED_DATE = CASE WHEN PAPPROVED_BY IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE SYSDATE END,
                    REJECTED_BY = NULL,
                    REJECTED_DATE = NULL,
                    APPROV_REJECT_REMARK = PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK,
                    MODIFIED_BY = PMODIFIED_BY,
                    MODIFIED_DATE = SYSDATE,
                    UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
                    UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
                    UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID = NULL,
                    UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME = NULL,
                    UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_DATE = NULL,
                    JOB_PROGRESS_FLAG = 1,
                    STATUS_ID = PSTATUS_ID,
                    HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH = PHOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH,
                    LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH = PLIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH,
                    HOTO_OFFER_LEN_UPD_BY = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME
                WHERE JOB_PROGRESS_ID   = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;               
              UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS SET JOB_FLAG = 1 WHERE JOB_ID = VJOB_ID;     
              
            POUTMSG :='SUCCESS|HOTO process completed and Request closed';
        END;
        ELSE
BEGIN
                UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
                SET HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE = TO_DATE(PHOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                    LIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE = TO_DATE(PLIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                    APPROVED_BY = PAPPROVED_BY,
                    APPROVED_DATE = CASE WHEN PAPPROVED_BY IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE SYSDATE END,
                    REJECTED_BY = NULL,
                    REJECTED_DATE = NULL,
                    APPROV_REJECT_REMARK = PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK,
                    MODIFIED_BY = PMODIFIED_BY,
                    MODIFIED_DATE = SYSDATE,
                    UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
                    UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
                    UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID,
                    UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME,
                    UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_DATE = SYSDATE,
                    JOB_PROGRESS_FLAG = 1,
                    STATUS_ID = PSTATUS_ID,
                    HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH = PHOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH,
                    LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH = PLIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH,
                    HOTO_OFFER_LEN_UPD_BY = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME
                WHERE JOB_PROGRESS_ID = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;
SELECT JB.SPAN_ID,JB.LINK_ID,JB.MAINTENANCEZONECODE,JB.MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH,JB.SPAN_TYPE INTO VSPAN_ID,VLINK_ID,VMAINTZONECODE,JOB_NE_LENGTH,VSPAN_TYPE
          FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS JB WHERE JB.JOB_ID= VJOB_ID;
          
        IF 1 = 1 THEN
        BEGIN
             UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS SET MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH = VNELEG WHERE JOB_ID = VJOB_ID;    
             UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS SET NE_SPAN_LENGTH = VNELEG WHERE JOB_ID = VJOB_ID;
        END;
         
       POUTMSG :='SUCCESS|HOTO process partially completed';     
        END IF;                
END;
 
  
           
    
    EXCEPTION  
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
      ERROR_MESSAGE := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
      ROLLBACK;
      POUTMSG :='ERROR|Error occurred on record updation';
      PKG_FIBER_HOTO_COMP_TEST.INS_ERRORLOG(PMODIFIED_BY,'','DB : INS_UPD_WF_BY_CMM_FTTX',ERROR_CODE||' : '||ERROR_MESSAGE);
      
END INS_UPD_WF_BY_CMM_FTTX;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid IF (there's `OR` but ... what *or*?), too many unnecessary `BEGIN`s and `END`s, missing `END IF`. When fixed:

```
PROCEDURE INS_UPD_WF_BY_CMM_FTTX (
   PJOB_PROGRESS_ID        IN     TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.JOB_PROGRESS_ID%TYPE,
   PHOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE   IN     NVARCHAR2,
   PLIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE    IN     NVARCHAR2,
   PAPPROVED_BY            IN     TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.APPROVED_BY%TYPE,
   PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK   IN     TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.APPROV_REJECT_REMARK%TYPE,
   PMODIFIED_BY            IN     TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.MODIFIED_BY%TYPE,
   PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID    IN     TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID%TYPE,
   PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME  IN     TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME%TYPE,
   PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID    IN     TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID%TYPE,
   PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME  IN     TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME%TYPE,
   PSTATUS_ID              IN     TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.STATUS_ID%TYPE,
   PHOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH     IN     TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH%TYPE,
   PLIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH      IN     TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH%TYPE,
   POUTMSG                    OUT NVARCHAR2)
AS
   VCNT              NUMBER := 0;
   VCMMROUTE         NUMBER := 0;
   VCMMLIT           NUMBER := 0;
   VLENGTH_CHNG_CNT  NUMBER := 0;
   VJOB_ID           NUMBER;
   VSPAN_TYPE        NVARCHAR2 (20) := '';
   VSPAN_ID          NVARCHAR2 (50) := '';
   VLINK_ID          NVARCHAR2 (50) := '';
   VMAINTZONECODE    VARCHAR2 (50) := '';
   VNELEG            NUMBER;
   VNELEG1           NUMBER;
   VNELEG2           NUMBER;
   JOB_NE_LENGTH     NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO VLENGTH_CHNG_CNT
     FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
    WHERE     JOB_PROGRESS_ID = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID
          AND HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH = PHOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH
          AND LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH = PLIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH;

   SELECT DISTINCT JOB_ID
     INTO VJOB_ID
     FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
    WHERE JOB_PROGRESS_ID = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;

   IF PSTATUS_ID = 4
   THEN
      UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
         SET HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE = TO_DATE (PHOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
             LIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE = TO_DATE (PLIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
             APPROVED_BY = PAPPROVED_BY,
             APPROVED_DATE = CASE WHEN PAPPROVED_BY IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE SYSDATE END,
             REJECTED_BY = NULL,
             REJECTED_DATE = NULL,
             APPROV_REJECT_REMARK = PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK,
             MODIFIED_BY = PMODIFIED_BY,
             MODIFIED_DATE = SYSDATE,
             UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
             UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
             UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID = NULL,
             UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME = NULL,
             UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_DATE = NULL,
             JOB_PROGRESS_FLAG = 1,
             STATUS_ID = PSTATUS_ID,
             HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH = PHOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH,
             LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH = PLIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH,
             HOTO_OFFER_LEN_UPD_BY = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME
       WHERE JOB_PROGRESS_ID = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;

      UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
         SET JOB_FLAG = 1
       WHERE JOB_ID = VJOB_ID;

      POUTMSG := 'SUCCESS|HOTO process completed and Request closed';
   ELSE
      UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
         SET HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE = TO_DATE (PHOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
             LIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE = TO_DATE (PLIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
             APPROVED_BY = PAPPROVED_BY,
             APPROVED_DATE = CASE WHEN PAPPROVED_BY IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE SYSDATE END,
             REJECTED_BY = NULL,
             REJECTED_DATE = NULL,
             APPROV_REJECT_REMARK = PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK,
             MODIFIED_BY = PMODIFIED_BY,
             MODIFIED_DATE = SYSDATE,
             UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
             UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
             UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID,
             UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME,
             UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_DATE = SYSDATE,
             JOB_PROGRESS_FLAG = 1,
             STATUS_ID = PSTATUS_ID,
             HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH = PHOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH,
             LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH = PLIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH,
             HOTO_OFFER_LEN_UPD_BY = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME
       WHERE JOB_PROGRESS_ID = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;

      SELECT JB.SPAN_ID,
             JB.LINK_ID,
             JB.MAINTENANCEZONECODE,
             JB.MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH,
             JB.SPAN_TYPE
        INTO VSPAN_ID,
             VLINK_ID,
             VMAINTZONECODE,
             JOB_NE_LENGTH,
             VSPAN_TYPE
        FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS JB
       WHERE JB.JOB_ID = VJOB_ID;

      IF 1 = 1
      THEN
         --            BEGIN
         UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
            SET MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH = VNELEG
          WHERE JOB_ID = VJOB_ID;

         UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
            SET NE_SPAN_LENGTH = VNELEG
          WHERE JOB_ID = VJOB_ID;

         POUTMSG := 'SUCCESS|HOTO process partially completed';
      END IF;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
      ERROR_MESSAGE := SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200);
      ROLLBACK;
      POUTMSG := 'ERROR|Error occurred on record updation';
      PKG_FIBER_HOTO_COMP_TEST.INS_ERRORLOG (PMODIFIED_BY,
                                             '',
                                             'DB : INS_UPD_WF_BY_CMM_FTTX',
                                             ERROR_CODE || ' : ' || ERROR_MESSAGE);
END INS_UPD_WF_BY_CMM_FTTX;
```